# Simple Ruby program does not produce output

Tags: ruby

I wrote a basic ruby program with TextMate in Mac OS:

```
def hello
  puts " This works!"
end
```

name it `Check-it.rb`

I open a Terminal session, `cd` to the directory where the program is stored.

Then I type

```
ruby Check-it.rb
```

And nothing appears.

```
ruby -v
```

shows me the version, so it's there.
But with this and every other Ruby program, nothing appears.

Comment: You’ve defined a method, but your program never calls it.

Comment: Nice minimal verifiable example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others already pointed out. The code in your file

```
def hello
  puts " This works!"
end
```

*defines* a method called `hello` that outputs a string. But that method is never *called*. To actually call that method and run it change your code in the file to

```
def hello                          # this block defines the `hello` method
  puts " This works!"
end

hello                              # this line calls the method `hello`
```

Comment: Okay, I feel like the dumbest developer in the world.  That was the answer.  Thank you!

Comment: @RobertGavila I've been programming for 50 years now.  Everybody has "smack yourself on the forehead!" moments, it goes with the territory.  My own forehead is quite flat at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not calling this method at all. Call this method and then run your code, it will work.

Comment: Thank you Zain.  I get the prize for the dumbest developer in the world.

Comment: If this answer your issue, then kindly consider accepting my answer :)

Comment: Hi, Zain.  I clicked on the checkmark, if that helps.  Thank you.